# Making your own wildcard and recognize patterns to zip your list

Tags: algorithm, wildcard

I have an algorithm trouble, I don't know how to do it and how to call it (Does it have any specific name?)

For example, if I have this sequence:

```
000 CASE_01
001 CASE_02
010 CASE_03
011 CASE_02
100 CASE_02
101 CASE_01
110 CASE_01
111 CASE_01
```

I want to convert it in something like this:

```
000 CASE_01
0-1 CASE_02
010 CASE_03    
100 CASE_02
1-1 CASE_01
11- CASE_01
```

I have called it *wildcard* because I think is the most correct way...
They not necessarily have 3 bits, you must do it with ***n*** bits

If only I had the psudo-code I could write it to any language (Python in my way)

Comment: This seems ambiguous. Why choose `101 CASE_01 \n 11- CASE_01` over `1-1 CASE_01 \n 110 CASE_01`? They both seem equally valid to me.

Comment: it does not matter but I changed it if seems ambiguous

Comment: If all eight lines where CASE_01, would the desired result be something like `00-, 01-, 10-, 11-` or `0-0, 0-1, 1-0, 1-1` or simply `---` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below generates all possible wildcard strings for the number of bits encountered in the input (e.g. `--`, `-0`, `-1`, `0-`, `00`, `01`, `1-`, `10` and `11` for 2 bits), and also creates patterns where numbers are inverted and wildcards become 1 (so wildcard `0-1` has pattern `110`), and masks where numbers become 1 and wildcards become 0 (so wildcard `0-1` has mask `101`).
The binary numbers in the input are then XOR-ed with the patterns and AND-ed with the masks to check whether they fit a certain wildcard. If a wildcard has the required number of matching numbers (2 ^ number_of_wildcards), it is added to the output and the matching numbers are removed from the input.

Run the code snippet to see the algorithm in action with your example input, to which I added a fourth case with larger binary numbers.

```js
function wildcard(input) {
    var output = [], cases = [], wilds = [], patts = [], masks = [];

    var bits = groupCases(cases);
    for (var i = 0; i <= bits; i++) wilds[i] = [];
    wildStrings(bits);
    convertStrings(wilds, patts, "-01", "110");
    convertStrings(wilds, masks, "-01", "011");

    for (var c = 0; c < cases.length; c++) {
        for (var i = 0, j = Math.pow(2, bits); i <= bits; i++, j /= 2) {
            for (var k = 0; k < patts[i].length; k++) {
                var patt = patts[i][k];
                var mask = masks[i][k];
                var matches = [];
                for (var d = 0; d < cases[c].nums.length; d++) {
                    var num = cases[c].nums[d];
                    if (((num ^ patt) & mask) == mask) matches.push(d);
                }
                if (matches.length == j) {
                    output.push(wilds[i][k] + " " + cases[c].id);
                    for (var l = j - 1; l >= 0; l--) cases[c].nums.splice(matches[l], 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }            
    return output;

    function groupCases(cases) {
        var max = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            var num = parseInt(input[i], 2);
            if (num > max) max = num;
            var id = input[i].slice(input[i].indexOf(" ") + 1);
            var pos = 0;
            while (cases[pos] != undefined && cases[pos].id != id) ++pos;
            if (cases[pos] == undefined) cases[pos] = {id: id, nums: []};
            cases[pos].nums.push(num);
        }
        return Math.ceil(Math.log(max) / Math.log(2));
    }

    function wildStrings(len, wild, str) {
        wild = wild || 0;
        str = str || "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var w = (i == 0) ? 1 : 0;
            var s = str + ["-","0","1"][i];
            if (len > 1) wildStrings(len - 1, wild + w, s)
            else wilds[bits - wild - w].push(s);
        }
    }

    function convertStrings(input, output, from, to) {
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            output[i] = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < input[i].length; j++) {
                var str = input[i][j], s = "";
                for (var k = 0; k < str.length; k++) {
                    s += to.charAt(from.indexOf(str.charAt(k)));
                }
                output[i].push(parseInt(s, 2));
            }
        }
    }
}

var a = ["000 CASE_01", "001 CASE_02", "010 CASE_03", "1010 CASE_04",
         "011 CASE_02", "100 CASE_02", "1110 CASE_04", "101 CASE_01",
         "110 CASE_01", "1100 CASE_04", "1000 CASE_04", "111 CASE_01"];
var w = wildcard(a);
document.write(w.length + " wildcards:<BR><PRE>");
for (var i in w) document.write(w[i] + "<BR>");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the number of bits are variable... I will edit it in my question.

Comment: @Goyuso I adapted the code to work for any number of bits. It basically uses the algorithm described in my other answer, but instead of the 3 outer nested loops, the bit-patterns with which to compare the input are prepared first.